# API Platform: Is there a way to turn JWT authentication off entirely?

Tags: php, jwt, api-platform.com

I am using API Platform to build an API. I have an entity that represents a pairing between two devices, and I want to expose it.

In my entity definition, I have placed an `@ApiResource` before the start of the class.

The class now shows up automatically in my /docs screen:

[image: screenshot]

But when I try to visit `/pairings`, I get this response:

> {     "code": 401,    "message": "JWT Token not found" }

... and even when I comment out the two lines under the `access_control` section in my `security.yaml` this message persists.

**Is there a way to turn JWT authentication off entirely?**

Comment: You use LexikJwtBundle? API Platform doesn’t come with JWT support by default. If yes, you should take a look to the Symfony Security configuration: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Comment: Can you add you `security.yaml` please

Answer (score 0):

You might have enabled it in the api_platform configuration as explained [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/).